# Real life applications of the Lefschetz fixed point theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, fixed-point-theorems, big-list, applications

I'm looking for real life applications of the Lefschetz fixed point theorem.
I encountered this link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127045/fixed-point-theorems
However, I was hoping for applications from fields other then math.

Any ideas?

Comment: The work of Nash mentioned in the link is in economics.